# C# Mongodb search through lookup is expensive

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, lookup, database-performance

I am new to MongoDb and I have a performance issue.

I have 2 collection, "A" and "B"
"A" has a list with the _ids of "B" (like 50 elements)

What I want to achieve is to query "A" through the lookup of "B".

**Example**:
Let say A is Pokemons, and B is Moves.
I want to find all pokemon that have a move with power >= 30

What I do is something like this:

```
db.collection("pokemon")
    .aggregate()
    .lookup("Moves", "moves.move_id", "_id", "full_moves")
    .match({ $gte: { "full_moves.power": 30 }})
```

*(The code here is an example and is not C# but I am doing the same thing in C#)*

This with my structure it's working, I get what I want.
But the performance is terrible.
If I limit the result with Skip(n) and Limit(n + 20) it takes 2 second to perform the aggregation.
If I don't it takes like 28 seconds to perform a full lookup.

Is what I am doing correct? Is there any other way?

I know I should bring the document "B" as subdocument of "A" but "B" is big and with "A" having like 50 relations to "B" I think it's not an appropriate path.

Thanks

---

**Edit**
Here the Pkm document structure (is not definitive, I'm just playing around for understand mongodb)

**Pokemon**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(''),
    "abilities": [
        {
            //Simple object with 3 props
        }
    ],
    "experience": 64,
    "forms": [
        {
            //Simple object with 5 props
        }
    ],
    "height": 7,
    "id": 1,
    "is_default": true,
    "moves": [ //a pokemon can have like 50 moves
        {
            //Complex object with like 20 properties, some are Array but for search purpose I use only not nested properties like power, name etc
        }
    ],
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "stats": {
        "hp": 0,
        "attack": 0,
        "defense": 0,
        "special-attack": 0,
        "special-defense": 0,
        "speed": 0
    },
    "types": [
        {
        //simple object with 2 properties
        }
    ],
    "weight": 50
}
```

Also I run the filter in MongodbCompass with the explain and it says that for the collection the query operation ({ "moves.move.power": { $gte: 30 } }) took 4 ms

```
{
 "stage": "FETCH",
 "nReturned": 942,
 "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 4,
 "works": 12179,
 "advanced": 942,
 "needTime": 11236,
 "needYield": 0,
 "saveState": 12,
 "restoreState": 12,
 "isEOF": 1,
 "docsExamined": 942,
 "alreadyHasObj": 0
}
```

So probably the problem here is the manifestation of that data ?
I use the C# latest driver for mongodb and for manifest as List BsonDocument I use the LinQ "ToList()"

Answer (score 0):

This aggregation query might work a little better as the filtering is being done on the joining side.

```js
db.pokemon.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "Moves",
           let: { move_id: "$moves.move_id" },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $gte: [ "$power", 30 ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$_id",  "$$move_id" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }
           ],
           as: "full_moves"
         }
    }
])
```

You can then also add an index on the `Moves` collection of `{ power: 1}` which will make it a little more efficient.

However, you might want to reconsider re-modeling your document to be less relational, if the moves belong to the pokemon. Then just put the moves inside the pokemon document.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. 
It's difficult to translate what you wrote in C# but I will try it and check if it's better.

Also I will try to bring the "Move" as a subdocument of "Pokemon"
In your opinion having the "Pokemon" document with an array of 50 "Moves" where every Move have 20 properties is a good document model ? Is good for heavily reading operation ?
Thank you

Comment: I added the B document inside A array as a subdocument. 
I added the index and did the same thing as before => $match { $gte : [ "$power", 30] } 
But the time it tooks to get the information is the same as use a $lookup
I think I am doing something wrong here ._.

Comment: That seems odd, can you post the whole structure of your documents in your question? also if possible can you do a `.explain()` so we can take a look at what's going off https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

Comment: @theramenboy looks like it could be the serialization of all the data, could you maybe just project a few fields back with a `project` stage to see if you still have the same issue?